# Java EE User Management Library

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, authorization

I develop a fair number of Java EE apps for my clients and all of them involve the concept of user account creation, authentication and in some cases, authorization, organization hierarchies, etc.

I typically create (JPA) entities for users, organizations and setup their interrelations, writing EJB code for the workflow.

Is there a library or a framework that has already addressed this issue that I can re-use instead of having to build this setup anew for every new development?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the problems you descirbed are nicely solved with Spring security or [JBoss Seam security module](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule), I don't know spring but regarding the Seam module, you will find some examples in their repo on github.

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for your answer. I was hoping to find something readymade that has pre-built code for things like user sign up, password reset, account activation, deactivation, etc. Do you think Seam has something of that kind?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but if you'll find smth like that pls let me know :)